# CreateLayer function needs a basemap? How to create one in Cartodb.js?

Tags: carto, carto-js

I'm new to using CartoDB.js and I'm trying to use the `CreateLayer` function to create a new map on a webpage. (I don't want to link to a map already made on the CartoDB website.)

The online tutorials provide code samples, but don't explain how to create a basemap. Can I do that in Cartodb.js? Or do I have to use something like Leaflet?

Here's my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Online Mapping</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script>
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),  mapOptions);
    cartodb.createLayer(map, {
      user_name: 'samuelsmaggie',
      type: 'cartodb',
      sublayers: [{
        sql: "SELECT * FROM us_counties",
        cartocss: 

            #us_counties{
              polygon-fill: #8A4E8A;
              polygon-opacity: 0.8;
              polygon-comp-op: darken;
              line-color: #FFF;
              line-width: 0.3;
              line-opacity: 1;
            }

            }
                  }]
                }).done(function(layer) {
                map.addLayer(layer);


                });
</script>               
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Maps, you would have to specify the basemap type in the MapOptions. At the Google Maps JS docs you can also find the details for MapTypes [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeId).

You can also find more examples of CartoDB.js y Google Maps [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/tree/develop/examples/gmaps).

You can add [CartoDB basemaps](https://cartodb.com/basemaps) as an extra layer in your Leaflet or OpenLayer maps as follows:

Leaflet:

```
var layer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
});

var map = L.map('map', {
  scrollWheelZoom: false,
  center: [40.7127837, -74.0059413],
  zoom: 6
});

map.addLayer(layer);
```

OpenLayers 3:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        attributions: [new ol.Attribution({ html: ['&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'] })]
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```

The url attribute allows you to choose the basemap you want. My examples are using CartoDB Positron's basemap (light_all) but you can use any other ZXY URL basemap in there.